# Android block activity based on condition from base activity?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

For example.. `Activity A` attempts to start `Activity B`, however `Activity B` requires some state to exist before it is allowed to be shown (i.e. the user must first create some entity in another activity, or must have an active subscription, etc).

I have a `BaseActivity` that all my activities extend, and I'd like to show an `AlertDialog` describing the restriction and immediately finish the activity in the `BaseActivity#onCreate` method, however I get an error that the window leaks because the activity context no longer exists (because finish() was called), and passing the application context throws a different error. I can't put the `finish()` call in `onDismiss` because then the activity will still load behind the modal since Android modals do not block. I also attempted to override `startActivity` and simply disallow the activity to be shown altogether, however that seems even worse than putting conditionals everywhere because there are lots of ways to start activities, and a handful of those `startActivityX` methods would have to be overridden to achieve it that way.

Is there a generally good approach to this? I can't seem to find any documentation on it, but are there some kind of application level global hooks that I can implement to run those sort of checks and perform those actions?

Comment: Use onBackPressed() function for showing the alert dialog.

Comment: Leak window comes when someone is holding the reference to your activity that is destroyed.In your case i believe its due to the alert dialog.Also you cannot use application context for showing dialogs as they are attached to their activity.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up tracking the currently "active" `Activity` in my `Application` class via the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, setting the current `Activity` only in the `onActivityResumed` method and performing the checks I needed in my `BaseActivity#onCreate`, calling `finish()` when invalid and showing the `AlertDialog` using the currently set `Activity` from my `Application`

Hope this helps someone, here's some code (Kotlin):

```
// YourApplication.kt
class YourApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        ...
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
            ...
            override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity?) {
               currentActivity = activity
            }
        })
    }

    companion object {
        var currentActivity: Activity? = null
            private set
    }
}

// BaseActivity.kt
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (requiresActiveSubscription() && !SubscriptionService.hasActiveSubscription()) {
            finish()
            // show alert here using YourApplication.currentActivity as Context
        }
    }
}
```